# Redirects with Craft and nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm running into a few issues trying to set up 301/302 redirects with Craft and nginx. The legacy site has `/contact.php` paths which I would like to direct to `/info/` but when I visit `mysite.com/contact.php` it gives me the `No input file specified.` error.

I tried setting this up with Retour plugin, and inside of nginx files, but they both return `No input file` since there is no `contact.php` on my server.

Below is my nginx file for reference:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name mysite.com;
    root "/home/vagrant/mysite/public";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/mysite.error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.key;
}
```

I know Craft is doing some weird things here to avoid `index.php`, not sure how it affects my situation though. In addition to mapping `/contact.php` to `/info/`, I would also like to make `/gallery.php?c=category` to `/?filter=category`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the "No Input File" in your Nginx config, you'll need something like this inside if your php location handler:

```
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
```

That will cause it to run the query through Craft (via `index.php`) if the `.php` file doesn't exist, which then allows Retour to handle it.

You can see this works by hitting a random `.php` url on my site: https://nystudio107.com/woof.php

c.f.: https://github.com/nystudio107/nginx-craft/blob/master/sites-available/somedomain.com.conf#L106 & [Nginx-Craft](https://github.com/nystudio107/nginx-craft)

Comment: Looks like `/woof.php` still returns a 404! Would like to see `/woof/` instead. Thanks for your answer though, your plugins are amazing!

Comment: Yes, it could easily redirect if I set it up in Retour to do so. This was just showing that it is a Craft 404 (as evidenced by the custom 404 not found page). Once you make the change to the Nginx config that I mentioned, you then simply add the redirect you want via Retour.

Comment: In case I wasn't clear, the fundamental problem you're having is that your Nginx config doesn't allow files ending in `.php` to be routed through Craft if there is a 404 (because your `.php` location handler doesn't pass them off to Craft at last resort). This is what prevents Retour (or any other such plugin) from working with `.php` files.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing php files in the public directory to redirect users:

**public/gallery.php**

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']){
    parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    if($q){
        header("Location: https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/?filter=".$q);
        die();
    } else {
        header("Location: https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/");
        die();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I would recommend doing it the way I noted, as it bottlenecks your 404 redirects, and allows you to add as many new ones as you need to without having to create new `.php` files to do so.