# Retour Redirects with Craft and nginx

Tags: nginx, plugin-retour

I have come across an issue whilst using the [Retour plugin](https://github.com/nystudio107/retour) for Craft similar to the question raised [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/22006/redirects-with-craft-and-nginx) but this is a redirect with a URL using the .htm extension and not .php.

Any ideas why this would not work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retour only works if the 404 actually is handled by Craft; my guess is that your Nginx config somehow is not passing along the 404 to Craft.

Comment: Just in case it helps anyone else, the problem was this directive in our nginx expires partial where we had a line for static caching of htm(l) files. This actually came from an older version of Andrew’s nginx config here: https://github.com/nystudio107/nginx-craft/blob/master/nginx-partials/expires.conf … which has since changed.

`# cache.appcache, your document html and data
location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html|json)$ {
    expires -1;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/static.log;
}`